# GoogleChart Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, google-visualization

I want to make a chart from datas in my local API. I can create piechart from my local in db. but i cant make the chart from my local API even though I already got the data.

My model where I get the localapi

```
    {
        $data = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/s_api/product/rSum.php');
        $data = json_decode($data->records);
        var_dump($data);
        return $data;
    }
```

Controller where I get the function from my model and display it on my view

```
public function index() 
    { 
        $this->load->view('piechart'); 
    } 

    public function getD()
    {
        $data = $this->model_data->getD();

        $responce->cols[] = array( 
            "id" => "", 
            "label" => "Topping", 
            "pattern" => "", 
            "type" => "string" 
        ); 
        $responce->cols[] = array( 
            "id" => "", 
            "label" => "Total", 
            "pattern" => "", 
            "type" => "number" 
        ); 
        foreach($data as $d) 
        { 
            $responce->rows[]["c"] = array( 
                array( 
                    "v" => "$d->month", 
                    "f" => null 
                ) , 
                array( 
                    "v" => (int)$d->qor, 
                    "f" => null 
                ) 
            ); 
        } 

        echo json_encode($responce);

    }
```

````
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at gvjs_Uh (jsapi_compiled_format_module.js:209)
    at new gvjs_R (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:131)
    at drawChartD ((index):39)```

but i dont know even I checked index 39 where the visualization of datatable but it just empty in inspection
````

Comment: Just a guess, but it seems that you return decoded JSON from controller, while google API expects proper JSON (encoded)

Comment: @Andrey So i deleted the decode json in my model or encode in controller? i try both its not working.

Comment: string(173) "{"records":[{"month":"1","qor":"1611","qod":"1087","qoi":"1405"},{"month":"2","qor":"2551","qod":"1773","qoi":"1070"},{"month":"12","qor":"2065","qod":"2432","qoi":"2702"}]}"

that one? @WhiteHat

Comment: is this the json being sent to the google chart? I don't see a reference to `cols` or `rows` as in the code above...